# How to write return page in php use if(isset($_GET['type']==1){}

Tags: php, html

I build a form in PHP/HTML. There are two pages in the form.
The first page for form input, and the second page for actions. The second page includes two actions. The first action for upload file, and the second action for download file calling rest web service java eclipse. This is the function I used:

```
if(isset($_GET['type'])){

}
```

This is not working. 
How can I calling type "if" in HTML? How can I write return value?

this is my code

```
<?
//upload file
if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']==1){
    //detect ie type
    // $efec_date = 18-10-2012
    $day_awal   = substr($efec_date,0,2);
    $month_awal = substr($efec_date,3,2);
    $year_awal  = substr($efec_date,6,4);

  ereg('MSIE ([0-9]\.[0-9])',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$reg);
  if(!isset($reg[1])) {
    $version = -1;
  } else {
    $version = floatval($reg[1]);
  }

    $get_path = rtrim($get_path);
    $slash_com = "\+";

    $slash = str_replace("+","",$slash_com);
    $get_path = str_replace("\\\\","$slash",$get_path);
    $get_paths = str_replace("\\","+",$get_path);
    $new_path = str_replace("++","$slash",$get_paths);
    $new_path = str_replace("D", "d",$new_path);
//echo "c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\payroll\\apps\\dec.exe ".$new_path." c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\payroll\\doc\\temp\\$dec_name 123";
//echo "<br><br>";
//check user
if ($_SESSION['agent'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] || $_SESSION['ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
{
    echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
}

//echo "--".$efec_date;
// $efec_date = 18-10-2012

if ($status != 01) {
        echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\"\Sorry, This Web Page is Only For Inputer\");";
        echo "javascript:history.back();</script>";
        exit;
}

if ( $_POST[account] == '-- Select --')
{
        //echo "--".$_GET[account]."++" ;
        echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\"\Account Debit Tidak Boleh Kosong\");";
        echo "javascript:history.back();</script>";
        exit;
}           


    if (!login_check()) {
        echo "<script>window.location='logout.php'</script>";
        exit(0);
    } else {


//activated date
if($efec_date == '') {
    echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\"\Please Fill in the Effective Date\");javascript:history.back();</script>";
    exit();
} 

$jan = 1;
$feb = 2;
$mar = 3; 
$apr = 4;
$mei = 5;
$jun = 6;
$jul = 7;
$ags = 8;
$sep = 9;
$okt = 10;
$nov = 11;
$des = 12;

/*if (substr($feb,0,1) == $month_awal and $day_awal > $feb_awal ) {
    echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\"\Tidak Bisa Melewati Batas Tanggal Pada Bulan Februari\");javascript:history.back();</script>";
    exit();
    } else */if (substr($apr,0,1) == $month_awal and $day_awal > 30  ) {
    echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\"\Tidak Bisa Melewati Batas Tanggal Pada Bulan April\");javascript:history.back();</script>";
    exit();
    } else if (substr($jun,0,1) == $month_awal and $day_awal > 30  ) {
    echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\"Tidak Bisa Melewati Batas Tanggal Pada Bulan Juni\");javascript:history.back();</script>";
    exit();
    } else if (substr($sep,0,1) == $month_awal and $day_awal > 30   ) {
    echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\"Tidak Bisa Melewati Batas Tanggal Pada Bulan September\");javascript:history.back();</script>";
    exit();
    } else if (substr($nov,0,2) == $month_awal and $day_awal > 30 ) {
    echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\"Tidak Bisa Melewati Batas Tanggal Pada Bulan November\");javascript:history.back();</script>";
    exit();
    }


//buat javascript lengkapi upload terlebih dahulu
$pr_day = date("d");
$pr_month = date("m");
$sub_pr_month = substr(0,1,$pr_month);
    if($sub_pr_month == "0" ) {
        $pr_month = str_replace("0","",$pr_month);
    }
$pr_year = date("Y");

$tanggal_upload     = $pr_day.$pr_month.$pr_year;
$tanggal_efektif    = $day_awal.$month_awal.$year_awal;


if ( $pr_year > $year_awal ) {
    echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\"Sorry, Date cannot be Smaller Than Today Tahun \");javascript:history.back();</script>";
    exit();
    } else if ( $pr_month > $month_awal ) { 
    echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\"Sorry, Date cannot be Smaller Than Today bulan       \");javascript:history.back();</script>";
    exit();
    }

/*
if ($pr_day > $day_awal or $pr_month > $month_awal or $pr_year > $year_awal) {
    echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\"Sorry, Date cannot be Smaller Than Today\");javascript:history.back();</script>";
    exit();
}
*/
if (strlen($month_awal) == 1) {

    $month_awal = "0".$month_awal;

}

$date_act = "".$year_awal."".$month_awal."".$day_awal;
$date_format = "".$year_awal."-".$month_awal."-".$day_awal;

// first, set some variables
// make a note of the current working directory, relative to root.
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

// make a note of the directory that will recieve the uploaded files
$uploadsDirectory = APP_DIR. '/doc/payroll/';

// make a note of the location of the upload form in case we need it
$uploadForm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'index_account_001.php?page=upload-form3.html';

// make a note of the location of the success page
$uploadSuccess = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'index_account_001.php?page=upload-success3.html';

// name of the fieldname used for the file in the HTML form
$fieldname = 'file';

// Now let's deal with the upload
function error($error, $location = 'direct_page2.php', $seconds = 5)
{
    //header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");
    echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"'."\n".
    '"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'."\n\n".
    '<html lang="en">'."\n".
    '   <head>'."\n".
    '       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">'."\n\n".
    '       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">'."\n\n".
    '   <title>Upload error</title>'."\n\n".
    '   </head>'."\n\n".
    '   <body>'."\n\n".
    '   <div>'."\n\n".
    '       <h1>Upload failure</h1>'."\n\n".
    '       <p>An error has occured: '."\n\n".
    '       <span class="red">' . $error . '...</span>'."\n\n".
    '       The upload form is reloading in 5 seconds</p>'."\n\n".
    '    </div>'."\n\n".
    '</html>';
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"5;url=direct_page2.php\">";
    exit;//
} // end error handler

// possible PHP upload errors
$error = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded', 
                2 => 'HTML form max file size exceeded', 
                3 => 'File upload was only partial', 
                4 => 'No file was attached');

// check the upload form was actually submitted else print form
!isset($_POST['submit'])
    or error('The upload form is neaded', $uploadForm);

// check for standard uploading errors
($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0)
    or error($error[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm);

// check that the file we are working on really was an HTTP upload
@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
    or error('Not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);


if(isHoliday($efec_date)){
    error('Effective date not a workday', $uploadForm);
}


// validation... since this is an file enc upload script we 
// should run a check to make sure the upload is an enc file
$file = "".$_FILES[$fieldname]['name'];
//$path = "".$_FILES;
//print_r($_FILES);

if (substr($file, -3) != "enc") {
        error('Only ENC File uploads are allowed', $uploadForm);
} else {

}

// make a unique filename for the uploaded file and check it is 
// not taken... if it is keep trying until we find a vacant one

$now = time();

$upload_file = $pyrCode.$now.".enc";

while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$upload_file))
{
    $now++;
}

$data = array(
                'nameFile'  => $uploadsDirectory.$upload_file,
                'status' => '0',
                'companyId' => $pyrCode,
                'account_number' => $account,
                'effective_date' => $date_format
                //'effective_date' => '2019-11-22'
            );

$payload =json_encode($data);

$url = "http://localhost:8181/save";

$curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'content-type: application/json',
            'content-length: '.strlen($payload)
        ));

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    //echo $result;
    //die();

            // $insert = $this->curl->simple_post($this->API.'/payroll', $data, array(CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 10));



// now let's move the file to its final and allocate it with the new filename
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename)
    or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission '.$uploadFilename, $uploadForm);



// If you got this far, everything has worked and the file has been successfully saved.
// We are now going to redirect the client to the success page.
echo "<script> window.location='index_account_001.php?page=upload-success2.html&file=$file&dec_name=$dec_name&date_act=$date_act&account=$account' </script>";

// make an error handler which will be used if the upload fails

    }
} else { echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>"; }

echo $

}


//download file 
if(isset($_GET['type'])&& $_GET['type']==2){
    $url ='http://localhost:8181/getKey/{company_id}';
    $fields= array('company_id' => $pyrCode);
    $method = 'GET';

    $curl = curl_init();
    // set the url, GET vars, GET data
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);

    //Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    //Excecute
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($curl));
    }

    /*$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);*/

    //$response = json_decode($json_response, true);

    file_put_contents("key.key", $result);
    header('Content-Type: application/pgp-keys');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"key.key\""); 
    echo $result;


}

?>
```

This is my calling action in html

```
<a href="<? echo"index_account_001.php?page=upload-processor2?type=2.html"; ?>">Download Key File</a>
```

Comment: perhaps try `intval( $_GET['type'] )==1` etc to cast the querystring variable explicitly to an integer

Comment: Mutliple request parameters are joined with `&`: `index_account_001.php?page=upload-processor2&type=2.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a header location for return in page if your condition becomes true.

```
if(isset($_GET['type']==1)){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

and for send multiple values in a href link in PHP you can use this code

```
<a href="index_account_001.php?page=upload-processor2&type=2">Download Key File</a>
```

Comment: i just show you how to redirect in php and i use your if condition just for demo purpose. @u_mulder

Comment: thank you @Darshan Patani this is work, and I have one question again for if(isset($_GET['type'])==2){ } Is the return value the same as before? use header("Location: index.php');?

Comment: @Maryati , yes you can use header("Location: index.php');

Comment: I have to use but, when I clicked  "Download Key File", The page responds logout automatically, and I can't download the file, there another way? @Darshan Patani, my code for download I have write above

Comment: you use any if condition on the download page for session expire ? @Maryati

Comment: please remove this condition in download.php for now and check.                        if ($_SESSION['agent'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] || $_SESSION['ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
{
    echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
}

Comment: @Maryati if your problem has been solved, please don't forget to tick my answer as correct answer.

Comment: yes sure @Darshan Patani, how can I tick your answer, because this is my first time I ask at stackoverflow

Comment: you tick my answer as correct please upward my answer so other can easily get my answer. @Maryati

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code for your requirement,

```
if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 1){
        header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: i have already show this and manage code brackets in answer @sun

Comment: thank you sun...  @sun I have one question again for if(isset($_GET['type'])==2){ } Is the return value the same as before? use header("Location: index.php');?

Comment: for download file?? @sun I have write this code, in up